# jQuery pop window on validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, popup

I have a username and password text box in asp.net. I would like to check it before I click the login button. Currently, I have few issues.

1. I check if username and password is empty then I display a message ("username and password are required"). The problem is that that message appears even if the username and password are not empty and it doesn't clear when I input something.
2. The second issue is that I would like to display that message in a jquery pop up window (instead of fade in effect I'm currently using).

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var userName = $('#user').val();
            var passWord = $('#password').val();
            if ($.trim(userName) == "" || $.trim(passWord) == "")
            {
                $('.error').fadeIn(100);
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
```

Here's html:

```
<div class="login">
        <div class="error" style="display:none">Username and password are required</div></br>
            <input type="text" id ="user" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
            <input type="password" id ="pass" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit">
    </div>
```

[Here is JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTgLK/)

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passward selector is wrong. Its ID is #pass but in your jQuery you typed "password". So it is always empty when it tries to validate.

Also, you can hide the error message every time before a validation is performed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                var userName = $('#user').val();
                var passWord = $('#pass').val();
                $('.error').hide();
                if ($.trim(userName) == "" || $.trim(passWord) == "") {
                    $('.error').fadeIn(100);
                    return false;
                }
            });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLGRa/

For popup, you can use jQuery UI's dialog:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as for clearing the error message when you type something, you could add a [Jquery 'focusin' Event](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) that targets both input fields, which would hide the message

```
$('#user, #pass').focusin(function () {
    //Hide my error message
});
```

Second of all, I wouldn't recommend using a modal to alert user that a field is wrong. It would be kind of annoying. I speak by experience. You need to make this as user-friendly as possible. I would recommend one of the following:

- Changing input field text color (ex: red)
- Changing input field border color
- Display a unique message next to the input field (ex: username required)

Answer (score 0):

change 
`<input type="password" id ="pass" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>`

to 
`<input type="password" id ="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>`